I encountered an error when trying to import redhat's Product Documentation for Migration Toolkit for Applications 6.2 in eclipse
I followed the installation steps on the website below, but encountered an error exception when executing the seventh step. I would like to ask if I did something wrong somewhere.
●website
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/migration_toolkit_for_applications/6.2/html/eclipse_plugin_guide/installing-plugin_eclipse-code-ready-studio-guide
●Prerequisites

Download eclipse
(https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-03/r)

Installing and configuring OpenJDK 17 (on Windows)
(https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/)

JBoss Tools, installed from the Eclipse Marketplace

Mylyn SDK and frameworks, installed with Eclipse

Install MTA6.2.0 from eclipse with Help → Install New Software

Accessing the MTA tools

Creating a run configuration


●Images
enter image description here、enter image description here、enter image description here
●error exception  
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.tools.windup.model.domain.ModelService.getModel()" because "this.modelService" is null
at org.jboss.tools.windup.ui.internal.launch.WindupInputTab.buildMigrationPaths(WindupInputTab.java:389)
at org.jboss.tools.windup.ui.internal.launch.WindupInputTab.createMigrationPathGroup(WindupInputTab.java:376)
at org.jboss.tools.windup.ui.internal.launch.WindupInputTab.createControl(WindupInputTab.java:87)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.showInstanceTabsFor(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:921)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.displayInstanceTabs(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:846)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.lambda$4(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:728)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:67)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:743)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:675)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:655)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.handleLaunchConfigurationSelectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1049)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.lambda$1(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:612)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:821)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:818)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1661)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1090)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:376)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.doInitialTreeSelection(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:658)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.initializeContent(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1185)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.createContents(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1094)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.create(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:378)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:788)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1238)
at org.jboss.tools.windup.ui.internal.editor.CreateRunConfigurationHandler.execute(CreateRunConfigurationHandler.java:56)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:438)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:449)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:475)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

I tried using other versions but encountered the same problem
